# "Activation context generation failed" complaint trying to add an application manifest

Tags: .net, manifest, side-by-side

I'm trying to add an application manifest that requires elevation to my .NET 2.0 EXE.
I've done that for a simple EXE and it worked without any problems, but on this more complex EXE it's not working.

My EXE has a config file and a lot of dependencies of other DLLs in my solution.

When I start the EXE, I get a SideBySide error saying "`Activation context generation failed for "C:\MyCompany.MyProduct.WinUI.exe".Error in manifest or policy file "C:\MyCompany.MyProduct.WinUI.exe.Config" on line 1. Invalid Xml syntax.`"

What does my config file have to do with the manifest file?  Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
                xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
                xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="2.10.0.0" name="MyCompany.MyProduct.WinUI"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</asmv1:assembly>
```

Comment: Just to make sure it isn't a typo, but your manifest file does have the closing </asmv1:assembly> tag in it, yes?

Comment: Also, can you post the code for your WinUI.exe.Config file. There could be a problem there.

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution.

The encoding specified in the MyCompany.MyProduct.WinUI.exe.Config is not supported.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

I changed the encoding to utf-8, and everything work fine...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: this did the trick. i suppose the manifest parser must be looking at the config files, even if only in passing.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't close the asmv1:assembly tag.

Also, try downloading [XML Notepad](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=72d6aa49-787d-4118-ba5f-4f30fe913628&displaylang=en) and loading your XML into it.  It's very good at telling you what you did wrong.

Comment: Sory for that... My file did contains the missing closing tag </asmv1:assembly>. I probably delete it when I was formatting the post..

Answer (score 0):

my issue with this was that i had invalid XML in my App,Config, an app setting element closing with two quotes -> ""

as soon as i removed the second -> " my console app worked fine, a misleading error no doute.